# Constraining Shuffle when repeating and randomising a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get the ordering for some stimuli during an experiment worked out but having a slight problem with the following. So I have a list of 8 images, each of a digit 1 - 8. I need to show 2 digits on each trial. So each digit needs to be shown 9 times, with a total of 72 presentations all up. However, the same two digits cannot appear on the same trial. Also, I can't have the same two digits appearing together frequently.

I have tried a few different ways but keep getting the odd double up.

So eg. if I do something like:

```
images = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];  
images = Shuffle(images);
images = repmat(images, 1, 9);  
images = reshape(images, 36, 2);  
images = shake(images, 2) %where shake is a function that shuffles the rows
```

it doesn't give you the same number in the same row, but the same numbers always appear together, eg. you would get 3 6, then 6 3

As it does not necessarily have to be in the form of a 36 x 2 matric, it could be 72 x 1 vector - I was thinking one option may be to repeat and shuffle the row, putting the shuffle within a loop to constrain any double ups,

e.g.

```
not_good = true;  
while not_good  
not_good = false;  
vector = shuffle(repeated_vector);  
if (gets a bit hazy here, something to say if two consecutive values are equal)  
not_good = true;  
end  
end
```

But honestly I am open to suggestions, and any help / clarifications would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am still not very clear: you want to repeatedly select 2 digits from 8 images (without replacement).. Are there any other requirements? Maybe you are looking for the [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) function: `nchoosek(1:8,2)` gives all combinations of 8 digits taken 2 at a time.

Comment: @Lau: If the answer was useful to you, then you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow next to the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Amro said: use `nchoosek` to get all pairs of images.

Then randomise the order with `randperm`.

```
nImages = 8;
pairs = nchoosek(1:nImages, 2);
nPairs = size(pairs, 1);
order = randperm(nPairs);
randomisedPairs = pairs(order, :)
```